# How to pull content of a div into a String

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am looking for a way to pull the html or text content of a  so I could work with it for a method which validates links amongst text of messages displays on a webpage.  I am using selenium and java.

```
<div>
    "This link"
    <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
    "exists." 
</div>
```

I have been researching ways to pull the html of the link from a single message and most of what I have encountered allows you to pull the text of the 'href' attribute or the link text.  It may not be possible.  Preferably, I would like to pull all the content from the div.

I have tried something similar to this below but it returns 'http://www.google.com'.

```
WebElement e = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
String content = e.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

I have also tried using xpaths using contains() and text().  Both return the text of link but not anything else.

Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a/.."));
```

It will select the parent element, the `div` in this case, of every `a`. If you want to add a predicate (that is, a condition) for which to filter, you can do this:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[contains(@href, 'http:')]/.."));
```

I chose `//` as start, which searches the whole document. If you want to search only a part, change that to an XPath expression that only selects that part.

Comment: (not sure it is `By.xPath()` or `By.xpath()` or `By.XPATH()`, as apparently, it may depend on the host language of Selenium that you have chosen).

Comment: I am using java.   The xpath("//a/..") worked like a charm.   It was able to pull the html link for me.   Now I am trying to figure out how to pull the text around the link at the same too.   Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1397534, that depens on how that is structured and what you mean by "around the link": before and after the link, the linktext, the title-text, etc. You can use XPath to get siblings (`following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling`), to get the parent, the parent's siblings etc. If you are unsure what to do, try it first on http://www.xpathtester.com or with FirePath or similar tools. If you can't work it out, post a new question. and if this answer helped you, feel free to upvote and/or accept it ;).

Comment: @user1397534, from your question, you can get the text nodes "this link" and "exists" by using `//a/parent::div/text()`, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.   I got it working.    Thanks.